# Creating a CLI (Shell?) in Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am very newbie in Python but I have to implement for school a command line interpreter in Python language, but I am kinda lost in how to do that.

I have already read some tutorials and created a simple file called functions.py where i include some simple functions like this:

```
def delete(loc):
    if os.path.exists(loc) == True:
        os.remove(loc)
        print "Removed"
    else:
        print "File not exists"
```

Now.. here is the thing.. in order to use this I must import it inside the python command interpreter, like...

```
import functions
functions.delete("file to delete")
```

How can I make a Shell/CLI so instead of have to write all of this I can just write like:

```
delete file_name
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think my definition of "CLI" differs somewhat. You want to write an interpreter for a small "programming language" (DSL), right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or if you want a cmd shell, you could use the cmd lib. It offers python interfaces to making command lines.
http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html

Answer (score 4):

I think you should now to use simple `argparse` module to get command line arguments

```
import argparse

from functions import delete

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file')

args = parser.parse_args()

delete(args.file)
```

Hope this should work for you

Sultan

Comment: After just add execution bit chmod +x delete.py and run it ./delete -f SOME_FILE

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check my personal REPL for some inspiration. I wrote it during [a tutorial series](http://nixtu.blogspot.com/2010/01/placidity-part-13-analysis.html). Actual source may be found [here](https://github.com/bebraw/Placidity). It probably does a few things you won't need... Still it could be a good read. :)