# Custom interactive terminal (CLI) with autocompletion on classes and objects

Tags: python, python-interactive, interactive-shell

I would like to have an interactive prompt similar to IPython within a program.

The features I would like to have are:

- Custom prompt
- Auto-completion on object's methods and attributes
- Execution of methods, read/write attributes
- Display docstring on error

So far I've been playing with `readline` with an auto-completion callback function and magic methods such as `__dir__`, `__doc__` or `__dict__`.

I am sure I can implement such solution, but I am looking for an existing module that can do the job for me.

In my idea I would like to use it like this:

```
class Foo:
    def Say(self): 
        return "The answer is 42"
foo = Foo()

cli = Cli() # The terminal interface I want to have
cli.RegisterObject(foo, showAttributes = True, showProtected = True)
cli.AddCommand('exit', exit)
cli.Start(defaultPrompt = ">")
```

A friend advised me to use IPython instead of a custom solution. Unfortunately IPython is too open for my application where newbies will get confused for sure. I don't want the final user to have access to everything.

At the end we will have something like this:

```
$ ./cli.py
>foo.<tab>
Say
>foo.Say()
The answer is 42
>bar.AreYouHere()
Unknown command!
>exit
```

Some related questions are:

- [Custom interactive shell with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937564/custom-interactive-shell-with-python?rq=1)
- [Custom Interactive shell with AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226236/custom-interactive-shell-with-autocomplete?rq=1)
- [Simulating cli shell with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499646/simulating-cli-shell-with-python)
- [Creating a CLI (Shell?) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772847/creating-a-cli-shell-in-python?rq=1)

Unfortunately the answers advise to use [cmd](https://pymotw.com/2/cmd/) module which is not very much what I need.

Comment: [Embed IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#embedding).  Better than making something _like_ IPython, because it _is_ IPython. :-)

Comment: Made it an actual answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Embed IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html#embedding). Better than making something like IPython, because it is IPython.

At a minimum, launching an IPython session involves:

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

There's a lot of additional configuration options available (including examples) in the [IPython Reference](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/reference.html)